# Deselect all objects (also on hidden layers)

Tags: selection-tools, layers

How can I deselect all object on all layers? Key A only works for current layer.

I have 20 layers, with different game buildings and before exporting I need to select what to export. If I forgot to deselect on different layer it will get exported too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can press <kbd>`</kbd> which is usually found immediately to the left of the <kbd>1</kbd> and directly above <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

This will make every layer visible so now using <kbd>a</kbd> will function as you would like it to.

Or you could just select something using a mouse/pen click, this will also release any hidden layer selections.

Comment: Any luck? The answer is still there. :)

Comment: That comment was based on a brain-fart, I've erased it.  For some reason I temporarily started hovering the cursor over the layers panel while pressing ~ and that's why I mistakenly thought the feature stopped working.  The cursor must be over the 3D Viewport.

Answer (score 4):

On a localized keyboard this key is often only accessible with a modifier like <kbd>Shift</kbd>. If it doesn't work as described by Marc check the settings in the *User Preferences*:

[image]

Note that this key can be configured separately for the different modes. In other modes than 3D-View it defaults to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>'</kbd>.